# Unable to create /.oauth-credentials directory

Tags: java, android, oauth, youtube-data-api

I am implementing a android app where users subscribe to a assigned youtube channel.I am using google api client library .I have got the client json file from developers console.

I have used the code from google api samples such as add `subsription.java` file and `auth.java` for authorization and storing o-auth credentials

```
 private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";
 public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore) throws IOException {

  // Load client secrets. 
  Reader clientSecretReader = new InputStreamReader(Auth.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secrets.json"));
  GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, clientSecretReader); 

  // Checks that the defaults have been replaced (Default = "Enter X here").    

  // This creates the credentials datastore at ~/.oauth-credentials/${credentialDatastore} 
  FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/" + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY));
  DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);
```

I am getting a IO exception unable to create directory ./o-authcredentials.Please guide me on how to solve this exception

Answer (score 1):

I passed my `MainActivity` as parameter to the function `authorize` for being able to get a path to datastore without using the code `System.getProperty("user.home")`, which always returned empty string. So I got:

```
import android.util.Log;

public class Auth {
private static final String CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY = ".oauth-credentials";
private final static String TAG = Auth.class.getSimpleName();

public static Credential authorize(List<String> scopes, String credentialDatastore, MainActivity mainActivity) throws Exception {
    ...
    String dataDir = mainActivity.getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
    String storePath = dataDir + File.separator + CREDENTIALS_DIRECTORY;
    Log.d(TAG, "storePath: " + storePath);

    File file=new File(storePath);
    FileDataStoreFactory fileDataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(file);
    Log.d(TAG, "fileDataStoreFactory  successfully created");

    DataStore<StoredCredential> datastore = fileDataStoreFactory.getDataStore(credentialDatastore);
    Log.d(TAG, "datastore  successfully retrieved if existed or created if not existed yet");
    ...
```